# Loopback | command line argument for loading data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, loopbackjs, loopback

For my Loopback project, I need to load a huge data set from csv.

Boot script takes nearly 30s to complete the data load. so its not an option.

My plan is to load data only when loop back is started with some argument.

like

```
node . --load-data
```

or

```
npm run load-data
```